# error with split off code not working/ flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Working in flutter and having issues getting my code to work. it was working previously and it was getting a parent widget error and unbounded errors. I had some formatting issues i was working through with the appbar I was working through. currently I have the app bar working as I want it, but nothing will render below, and I am getting an error telling me i cant be null, but i cant figure out why not? and what i need to do to get it to work.

My code:
main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'widgets/alertsfeeddata.dart';
import 'widgets/bullbearindicator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(75),
            child: Image.asset('assets/logos/1.png'),
          ),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(5),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 5,
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const BullBearIndicator(
              key: null,
            ),
            Align(
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircularPercentIndicator(
                          radius: 45.0,
                          lineWidth: 4.0,
                          percent: 0.10,
                          center: const Text("10%"),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          progressColor: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        ),
                        CircularPercentIndicator(
                          radius: 45.0,
                          lineWidth: 4.0,
                          percent: 0.30,
                          center: const Text("30%"),
                          progressColor: Colors.orange,
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        ),
                        CircularPercentIndicator(
                          radius: 45.0,
                          lineWidth: 4.0,
                          percent: 0.60,
                          center: const Text("60%"),
                          progressColor: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                          child: WebhookDataList(),
                        ),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

BullBearIndicator:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

class BullBearIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final double totAggr;
  final double btc;
  final double eth;
  final double alt;

  const BullBearIndicator({
    required Key key,
    this.totAggr = 0.88,
    this.btc = 0.71,
    this.eth = 0.71,
    this.alt = 0.78,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 130.0,
      animation: true,
      animationDuration: 1200,
      lineWidth: 15.0,
      percent: totAggr,
      center: CircularPercentIndicator(
        radius: 108.0,
        lineWidth: 12.5,
        animation: true,
        percent: btc,
        center: CircularPercentIndicator(
          radius: 90.0,
          lineWidth: 12.5,
          animation: true,
          percent: eth,
          center: CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 72,
            lineWidth: 12.5,
            percent: alt,
            center: totAggr > 0.51
                ? Image.asset('assets/logos/bull.png')
                : Image.asset('assets/logos/bear.png'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            progressColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          progressColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        progressColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      footer: const Text(
        "BULL/BEAR",
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
      ),
      circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      progressColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```dart
const BullBearIndicator(),
```

Also, you need to change your code to:

```dart
const BullBearIndicator({
  this.totAggr = 0.88,
  this.btc = 0.71,
  this.eth = 0.71,
  this.alt = 0.78,
  super.key,
})
```

or

```dart
const BullBearIndicator({
  Key? key,
  this.totAggr = 0.88,
  this.btc = 0.71,
  this.eth = 0.71,
  this.alt = 0.78,
}) : super(key: key);
```